# Selenium-Wire unable to find element even after entering correct XPATH, does not downloads full source code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, browser-automation, seleniumwire

Hi everyone I have a simple script that I am using to automate form-filling task, code-

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

URL = 'https://book.housecallpro.com/book/Rapid-Clean-Restoration/c9fa32bd46114b4198441aa2d04f395e'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(10)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  
add_product_btn = '/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/button/div/div/svg'
add_product = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, add_product_btn)))
add_product.click()

# next_btn_xpath = '/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/button/div/div/span'
# next_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, next_btn_xpath)))
# next_btn.click()

driver.quit()
```

However even though providing correct `XPATH` of elements I want to interact with it does not finds them -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\homep\PJ\freelancer\form-filling-bot\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    add_product = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, add_product_btn)))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\homep\PJ\freelancer\form-filling-bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

when I do not use `WebDriverWait` it gives `NoSuchElementException`. It is a real pain, I tried accessing other elements and script fails all the time, I even tried downloading the full `html` source-code to check if there is any problem in loading the page, and maybe there is as it didn't saved full source-code from the site.

This is the first time I have come across this type of situation, as if sites use `dynamic-js-content` to load page content dynamically I simply use `Selenium` to scrape page source or perform automation task. Can it be fixed, if anybody has some thing I can try to fix this it would really be helpful, any insights, references to docs etc. will work as well, any help will be appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: you'll always have NoSuchElementException errors with browser generated xpath locators. Use relative xpaths

Comment: How, exactly, did you get that xpath value?  Did you type it yourself by hand?  Did you use some tool to generate it?

Comment: @JohnGordon I copied from browser inspection tool.

Comment: @SinanCetinkaya I think you are talking about "Copy XPath" and "Copy Full XPath" options under "Copy" option in browser inspection, have tried with both of them does not work.

Comment: You should start learning XPATH query language. Blindly using auto generated xpath locators is not the way to go

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution:-

At the time I posted this I didn't tried looking for `iframes` in the `html` document of the source code, I checked and found I `iframe` at very top hierarchy in the document then I tried to switch to that but I was switching to any other `iframe` after that I copied the `XPATH` of the right `iframe` and then tried switching to that `iframe` and it worked!